# Dictionary validation Cerberus use reserved keyword

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I have a python dictionary I am trying to validate using cerberus. However, one of the fields in my dict is called `"type"` which conflicts with the keyword `"type"` reserved by the cerberus parser.

Is there any way to get around this without having to change the original dictionary?

**Part in question**

```
    {
        {
            ...
            "db": {
                "type": "AzureTables",
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So without seeing the schema that you are using I am making an educated guess here.

```
schema = {
'db': {'type': 'dict',
       'schema': {
            'type': {'type': 'string'},
            'some_field': {'type': 'integer'}

       }
      }
}

document = {
      'db': {'type': 'AzureTables',
             'some_field': 5}
}
```

The above schema validates the document that follows with no errors. My guess is that you are missing the `schema` rule. Cerberus will let you use dictionary keys that are reserved if you put the keys in a `schema` rule as you can see above.